# Async method to download file returns before the file is downloaded

Tags: c#

I have one async method which downloads the file.

```
public async Task DownloadFile()
{
   await doDownload();
}
```

I call this method from the main method. The issue I'm facing is that the async method returns before it downloads the file.

Using Thread.Sleep() in main method fixes the issue. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: how are you calling `DownloadFile`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: DownloadFile().Wait(); though i shouldn't really say that.

Comment: Yet another example of "async await is awesome. Must use everywhere"

Comment: That's the whole purpose of async programming, so that a lengthy operation doesn't blocks the calling thread. The method does indeed returns immediately, then the rest of the method runs after the download completes (nothing here, but it could be). Depending on context, it's better not to use async here.

Comment: I'm calling it like DownloaFile() from the main method.

Comment: You need to show how you call DownloadFile().

Comment: public static void main()
{
    DownloadFile();
}

Comment: Are you doing asynchronous programming from a console app?  *Why?* There is no GUI to keep active! You are saying "my asynchronous call is returning before it is done", but that's the *definition* of "asynchronous call". It sounds like you don't want an asynchronous call in the first place so why are you making one? This question is confusing.

Comment: I'm using an API to download a file. It supports only async method.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to sleep the main thread as it kills responsiveness and introduces a potential for deadlock. If your download takes longer than you sleep for, then it fails. If you loop sleep to get around this and the file never downloads, you could Sleep forever.

First Option (not great) - This blocks the main thread until the task completes.

```
public static void main()
{
    downloadFile.Wait();
}
```

Second Option - Similar to option 1, this is also blocking operation but can be used to retrieve a returned result. Depending on your program complexity this can cause crashes.

```
public static void main()
{
    var someresult = downloadFile.Result;
}
```

Third Option  - Move your file operations into another method and out of your main thread so that you don't have to block the application. Then call that code and continue on with operations, and have your download notify whatever is waiting on the file download results. If your program needs the data from the download to function consider using the `Task.Wait()` option and plan for the file download to fail.